# Как получить все теги при выделении текста в contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть div с contenteditable. Например, в нем есть 4 теги **p** с текстом. И пользователь выбирает текст начиная с середины второго абзаца и до середины третьего. Есть ли возможность получить все p, которые входят в это выделение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ещё надо допиливать, но идея примерно такая:

```js
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function () {
  var s = getSelection()

  for (var a = s.anchorNode; a && a.tagName !== 'P'; a = a.parentElement);
  for (var b = s.focusNode;  b && b.tagName !== 'P'; b = b.parentElement);

  if (!a || !b || a.parentElement !== b.parentElement) return
  
  var res = [], els = a.parentElement.children

  if (a === b) {
    res.push(a)
  } else {
    for (var q=0; q<els.length; ++q) {
      if (els[q] === a || els[q] === b) {
        res.push(els[q])
        while (res.push(els[++q]), els[q] !== a && els[q] !== b);
        break
      }
    }
  }  
  
  console.log(res.map(function (x) { return x.textContent }).join("\n"))
})
```

```css
p { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<p>У меня есть div с contenteditable.</p>
<p>Например, в нем есть 4 теги p с текстом.</p>
<p>И пользователь выбирает текст начиная с середины второго абзаца и до середины третьего.</p>
<p>Есть ли возможность получить все p, которые входят в это выделение?</p>
```